# datepicker convert to timestamp keeping format for display

Tags: datapicker

I have the following calendar script(jQuery) and it works. Next I like to save the user selection to the database.
Database filed  type is : timestamp.

I like to keep the current date format found in the script for display in the input field for user readability
 but in the background i like to convert it to a timestamp , so that i 
 can save it to the database. how do i go about converting it to a timestamp?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#date").datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: '0M',
        maxDate: '+90D',    
        dateFormat: "d-MM-yy",  
       });
});
</script>

<p> Enter project expire date: <input type="text" name="date" id="date"/></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) to convert the string into a JavaScript Date. You can then call getTime() to get the milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. Divide by 1000 to get a Unix timestamp.

```
var dateString = $('#date').val();
var timestamp = Date.parse(dateString).getTime()/1000;
```